# Regular Expressions for some alphanumeric sentences

Tags: regex, matlab

Can anyone provide Regular expression for there statements--

`annotations/16/16366.eng`
`annotations/29/21345.eng`
`annotations/10/20132.eng`

And these type of statements. I have tried `'a(\w+).eng'` but, it did not worked.

Comment: Modify regex a bit (include `/` as valid character, escape `.`, remove unnecessary group): `a[\w/]+\.eng`. What is the goal?

Comment: Works Great, Than you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match alphanumeric separated by slashes, ending with .eng you can do:

```
(\w+\/\w+\/\w+\.eng)
```

Remember that `[` and `]` are used for sets. You can specify a word verbatim as a match, without any flags. If you wanted to match anything in the same format with annotations you can do:

```
annotations\/\w+\/\w+\.eng
```

Where `\/` escapes a `/` and `\.` escapes a period.

And to simplify it:

```
[\w/]*\.eng
```

Meaning "Match any repetitions of the set with alphanumeric characters `\w`, and `/` followed by `.eng'.